# Finding the max number of occurrences from the available result

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like -

```
Id  Result
A    1
B    2
C    1
B    1
C    1
A    2
B    1
B    2
C    1
A    1
B    2
```

Now I need to calculate how many 1's and 2's are there for each Id and then select the number whose frequency of occurrence is the greatest.

```
Id  Result
A    1
B    2
C    1
```

How can I do that? I have tried using the `table` function in some way but not able to use it effectively. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your expected result, I would expect A to have 2, not 1, or am I missing something?

Comment: He is not looking fo the max `Result` of A, but for the most frequent occurence of the combination `Id` and `Result` for each `Id`

Comment: Yes, thank you @rmuc8 and sorry for the misunderstanding Roman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can use `aggregate` in one step:

```
df <- structure(list(Id = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
Result = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L)),
.Names = c("Id", "Result"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L)
)

res <- aggregate(Result ~ Id, df, FUN=function(x){which.max(c(sum(x==1), sum(x==2)))})
res
```

Result:

```
  Id Result
1  A      1
2  B      2
3  C      1
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table` you can try (`df` is your `data.frame`):

```
require(data.table)
dt<-as.data.table(df)
dt[,list(times=.N),by=list(Id,Result)][,list(Result=Result[which.max(times)]),by=Id]
#   Id Result
#1:  A      1
#2:  B      2
#3:  C      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you can try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Id, Result) %>% summarize(n = n()) %>% group_by(Id) %>%
  filter(n == max(n)) %>% summarize(Result = Result)


  Id Result
1  A      1
2  B      2
3  C      1
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `table` and `ave`

```
subset(as.data.frame(table(df1)),ave(Freq, Id, FUN=max)==Freq, select=-3)
#   Id Result
# 1  A      1
# 3  C      1
# 5  B      2
```